# In Unity3d, how to work out speed required to travel distance at specific time, cannonball with Sin()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, pi, trigonometry

I'm moving an object in a cannonball pattern without a rigidbody, without addforce.  I need to work out how fast the cannonball should travel to reach its destination at the right time.

My code so far:

```
moveTimer += Time.deltaTime * ballSpeed;
Vector3 currentPos = Vector3.Lerp(startPos, endPos, moveTimer);
currentPos.y += height * Mathf.Sin(Mathf.Clamp01(moveTimer) * Mathf.PI);
this.transform.position = currentPos;
```

I know that by increasing 'ballSpeed', the cannonball will follow the same curve but faster.  Assuming I want to arrive at endPos in precisely 10 seconds, how do I calculate the ballSpeed required?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ballSpeed = 1f / 10f; // duration 10s
...
moveTimer += Time.deltaTime * ballSpeed;
Vector3 currentPos = Vector3.Lerp(startPos, endPos, moveTimer);
currentPos.y += height * Mathf.Sin(Mathf.Clamp01(moveTimer) * Mathf.PI);
this.transform.position = currentPos;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I saw you added something about distance before it was edited, but this one works very well.  Thank you!